# How to make auto popup menu items of android without clicking the menu button

Tags: android, menu

I have made some menu items, and the items popup when I click menu button of my android phone. But I want , when I shall enter the activity The menu items will auto popup without clicking the menu button...

```
public class SalesTrackerRoot extends Activity {
private static final int ORDER_ID = Menu.FIRST+1;
private static final int STORE_ID = Menu.FIRST+2;
private static final int SETTINGS_ID = Menu.FIRST+3;

private SalesTrackerDBAdapter mDbHelper;

/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.salestrackerroot);
    mDbHelper=new SalesTrackerDBAdapter(this);
    mDbHelper.open();
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    menu.add(Menu.NONE, ORDER_ID, Menu.NONE, "Order List").setAlphabeticShortcut('o');
    menu.add(Menu.NONE, STORE_ID, Menu.NONE, "Store Entry").setAlphabeticShortcut('s');
    menu.add(Menu.NONE, SETTINGS_ID, Menu.NONE, "Settings").setAlphabeticShortcut('e');

    return(super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu));
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case ORDER_ID:
             startActivity(new Intent(this, SalesOrderList.class));
            return(true);
        case STORE_ID:
            startActivity(new Intent(this, AddNewStoreName.class));     
            return(true);

        case SETTINGS_ID:
            startActivity(new Intent(this, SalesTrackerSettings.class));
            return(true);   
    }

    return(super.onOptionsItemSelected(item));
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your onCreate simply call to openOptionsMenu().